# Can I reset my Rocket League skill level?

Tags: rocket-league

I've been playing with keyboard and gotten up to level 20 (Pro). I'll be switching to an XBox controller soon and don't want to embarrass myself as I get accustomed to the new controls. Any way to reset my skill level (and/or the entire game? Don't mind losing all the items and stuff too)

Comment: I recently swapped over to the Steam Controller and I found the best solution to this issue was to simply play unranked games until I re-familiarized myself with the controls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot reset the level, but with the latest update you can hide it completely. In the Garage, the far right tab will let you select to either show or hide your skill level.

[image: Enable or disable level tag]